# Not able to build gnome-calendar on builder

Tags: c, gnome, gnome-builder

I am getting this error when building gnome-calendar using the builder tool provided in Gnome.

```
The state dir (/home/abhinavgorantla/hdd/code/opensource/gnome-calendar/.flatpak-builder) is not on the same filesystem as the target dir (/home/abhinavgorantla/.var/app/org.gnome.Builder/cache/gnome-builder/projects/gnome-calendar/flatpak/staging)
```

How can I fix this so gnome-calendar can be built properly? I am running this on Arch linux.

I tried building gnome-calendar. I was expecting it to get built and installed with the change i made to the code.

Answer (score 1):

I did not realise it when I read the error for the first few times. So I have my project in hdd, which is a different drive from where my home directory is. And gnome-builder for some reason is not able to build projects which are not on the home partition.